# File location doesn't return once an npm command has been run

Tags: windows, npm

Every time I run an npm command the current location doesn't return once it's finished.

Is there a way to fix this?

[image: turminal screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled node with nvm-windows and it fixed the problem.